# Laravel routes issue with Nginx

Tags: laravel, nginx

I've put my Laravel app files into `/var/www/html/api/v2`directory.

My nginx conf looks like this:

```
    listen                    80 default_server;
    root                      /var/www/html;
    index                     index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-de$

    location / {
            try_files                $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files                $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass             unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index            index.php;
            include                  fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param            SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi$
            fastcgi_param            PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
```

I want to access my routes like this: `[host]/api/v2/[route]`

But it is throwing **404** right now except for homepage.

Please let me know what could be wrong here.

Comment: Did you add server_name ?

Comment: @TuranZamanlı No, I'm catching all with default_server in listen directive.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
root   /var/www/html;
```

to

```
root   /var/www/html/..../public;
```

Then restart nginx

```
$ sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Comment: I actually want to access my routes like this: [host]/api/v2/[route]. With your solution it will open with [host] only.

Comment: This answer is correct.  The `public/` dir should *always* be your docroot - otherwise your code (including `.env` with passwords and keys etc) is visible to the world.  If you want some particular route prefix once you've done that, you set it up in your routes.  Don't confuse the physical layout of files on disk (which you shouldn't change) with the "virtual" URLs you can create within the app.